# Add Events and Variable to Dynamically created Component Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've a dynamically created component in my Angular app as follows:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<IMessage>(MessageComponent);
this.component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
this.component.instance.body = message;
```

It is equivalent to adding `<message [body]="message"></message>` in component's HTML.

Let's assume that, I want to achieve something like this in my dynamic component code:

`<message [body]="message" #form="my-form" (change)="myFunction()"></message>`

How do I bind these additional variable and change events inside by component's ts file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Input bindings and events outputs don't work automatically with dynamically created components. This is because the compiler creates the function that listens to child components events and the function that updates child component bindings based on the template it parses. Dynamic components are not specified in the template so the compiler doesn't create such functions. You can read here about these functions - 
[The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce). The function name is `updateDirectives`.

You have to manually update the properties and subscribe to events:

```
this.component.instance.body = message;
this.component.instance.change.subscribe();
```

This means that child component can't use `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook as it will never be triggered by Angular.

Also, query list bindings like these `#form` don't work as well. All you have access to is the instance of the component. So whatever directive exports itself as `my-form` should inject a host `MessageComponent` and attached the data associated with `my-form` to the component instance. Then parent component will be able to access it:

```
this.component.instance.formData;
```

Comment: I couldn't find change property on instance as you shown in this line "this.component.instance.change.subscribe();"

Comment: @WASIF, it's probably because in your custom component class an event emitter property has a different name

Comment: Ok right.I have this event in my child "@Output() clickToRemove = new EventEmitter();" and I can call this as "instance.clickToRemove" only but can't subscribe to this. VS Code gives compilation error on subscribe() method call. Using Angular 5. Kindly help me through this issue.

Comment: @WASIF, can you create a separate question and post a link here?

Comment: I wish I could post a question but I am banned now. If someone give me 2-3 up votes on my questions then I'll be able to ask questions.

Comment: by the way, your site AngularInDepth is awsome and little bit difficult as well because it is in depth :D.

Comment: still blocked ;(